# Twitter's latest OAuth system conflict

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth, bit.ly

I have a website..previously when I was uploading a new post in my blog..It was getting posted to twitter automatically. But since the new version of OAuth system..It no longer works...Can anybody help me to sort out what to change?

My code is :

```
'Twitter'=>array(
    'enabled' => true, //set to false to shut off twitter integration
    'username' => 'blogspott', //your twitter.com username
    'password' => 'W3Sw9OpW6HvZYl', //your twitter.com pasword
    'consumer_key' => 'TdQS15VHBdZNIrQ7RPqVQ',
    'consumer_secret' => 'B2Xe5h3lHXVXUgoCAxgAIdJDTeBf6AywRoGiTwB7I',
    'oauth_token' => '283508422-FkiIyZq2tpx1PQOyBLyWyomXY9OdMKxxSKGcg9d3',
    'oauth_token_secret' => '548kxcZCvhytdRkJ405QeWONvMyXNEpSZszIMEYU4W4',
    'tweet'=>'#%POST% for just %URL-TO-POST% %LINK%',

    // Bit.ly / URL Shortening
    // Within your Tweets, auto-append short URLs i.e., bit.ly/s8dJksm, to save on space. 
    // Sign up for an API account at http://bit.ly, and place the information
    // for that account in the box below
    'short_url'=>array(
        'append_short_url'=>false,  
        'short_url_provider'=>'bit.ly',   // current option: bit.ly only (default), more soon!
        'bitly'=>array(
            'login' => 'o_78ocugrkqtf',
            'api_key' => 'R_734dbe3be47605c405f4e19ec35eb617'
        ),
    )
),
```

I am using the right keys here..I've double checked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter did not change its OAuth system recently. It is not concerned by the controversial Twitter API 1.1. So verify that you are doing it just like Twitter asks and that you do not use deprecated endpoints (Twitter removed some of them recently).